# Extracting part of string through regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following list of string

```
mystring = [
'FOO_LG_06.ip', 
'FOO_LV_06.ip', 
'FOO_SP_06.ip', 
'FOO_LN_06.id',       
'FOO_LV_06.id', 
'FOO_SP_06.id']
```

What I want to do is to print it out so that it gives this:

```
LG.ip 
LV.ip 
SP.ip 
LN.id
LV.id 
SP.id
```

How can I do that in python?

I'm stuck with this code:

```
   for soth in mystring:
       print soth
```

In Perl we can do something like this for regex capture:

```
my ($part1,$part2) = $soth =~ /FOO_(\w+)_06(\.\w{2})/;
print "$part1";
print "$part2\n";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this in a manner similar to the one you know in perl, you can use `re.search`:

```
import re

mystring = [
'FOO_LG_06.ip', 
'FOO_LV_06.ip', 
'FOO_SP_06.ip', 
'FOO_LN_06.id',       
'FOO_LV_06.id', 
'FOO_SP_06.id']

for soth in mystring:
    matches = re.search(r'FOO_(\w+)_06(\.\w{2})', soth)
    print(matches.group(1) + matches.group(2))
```

`matches.group(1)` contains the first capture, `matches.group(2)` contains the second capture.

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/UjiNFm).

Answer (score 0):

different regex:

> > > p='[^*]+*([A-Z]+)[^.]+(..*)'

```
    >>> for soth in mystring:
    ...    match=re.search(p,soth)
    ...    print ''.join([match.group(1),match.group(2)])
```

Output:

LG.ip

LV.ip

SP.ip

LN.id

LV.id

SP.id